# How to understand or standardize javascript error coming from ajax via reject()?

Tags: javascript, promise

A typical error message in JS looks pretty straightforward: Error type, Line/column, Error text. 
Instead of it, when using a combination of ajax and promise I'm unable get it and do have something like this instead:

> {readyState: 4, setRequestHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ,
>   getResponseHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

I've tried to remove reject(error) to get this error unhandled, but instead console adds "Uncaught (in promise)" and again, that bulky array.

```
tinput.on("input",function(){
    textloop(tinput.val(),tinput.caret('pos')).then(function(a){
        console.log(a);
    }).catch(e) => { 
         console.log(e);
    });
});
function textloop = (txt, caret) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/modules/nlpassist/nlpajax.htm",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {"txt": txt, "caret": caret},
      success: function(data) {
        resolve(data)
      },
      error: function(error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    })
  });
};
```

Comment: Check the type of the `error` object.

Comment: It's an array/object, of course, and does not have 'type' property.

Comment: That's weird. This looks like an XHR object, but you've specified `jsonp` data type (which traditionally doesn't come with proper errors at all)

Comment: At least, this should generate an error in temporary callback function, but instead error passes into reject().